# After login, hasValidAccessToken is always true when using angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have implemented angular-oauth-oidc (version 12.1.0) with Angular 12.2. I have no problems login using Keycloak as the SSO, but I am having an strange behaviour from the library.

Everytime, after login, the methods `hasValidIdToken` and `hasValidAccessToken` are returning true even if the tokens are expired. It seems that the library is not validating the token expiracy.

My config file is as follows:

```typescript
export const authCodeFlowConfig: AuthConfig = {
    // Url of the Identity Provider
    issuer: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realmname',

    // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/landing',

    // The SPA's id. The SPA is registerd with this id at the auth-server
    clientId: 'client-name',

    responseType: 'code',

    // set the scope for the permissions the client should request
    // The first four are defined by OIDC.
    // Important: Request offline_access to get a refresh token
    // The api scope is a usecase specific one
    scope: 'openid profile email',

    showDebugInformation: true,
  };
```

I initialize the library with the following code:

```typescript
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
      if (this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
      else {
        this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
      }
    });
  }
```

And, finally, I check if the tokens are valid with the following conditional in a guard:

```typescript
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        var hasIdToken = this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken();
        var hasAccessToken = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();
        var hasAccess = (hasIdToken && hasAccessToken)
            
        if (!hasAccess) {
            console.log('AuthGuard: Token not valid');
            this.router.navigate(['landing']);
        }
        else {
            console.log('AuthGuard: Valid token');
        }
            
        return hasAccess;
}
```

This method always returns `true` if I login previously. Without a prior login, it returns `false` as expected.

If I use some other library for token validation, I get the expected result when validating an expired token.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnInit` you've posted will be asynchronous, and might take -say- 150ms to complete. Most likely your browser hits the guard *synchronously*, so *before* the initialization has run, and will therefor return the *old* state from storage on the access tokens.

You need to either:

- [Initialize in an `async` `APP_INITIALIZER`](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/0f45047bd1b90f2e677911173a953fb2cd7bc803/src/app/core/auth-app-initializer.factory.ts#L1-L5) to make sure nothing in the app runs before the discovery document is loaded and all that jazz; or
- Make [your guard asynchronous](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/0f45047bd1b90f2e677911173a953fb2cd7bc803/src/app/core/auth-guard.service.ts#L14-L21) and [make it wait for initialization on auth to be finished](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/0f45047bd1b90f2e677911173a953fb2cd7bc803/src/app/core/auth.service.ts#L18-L31)

You can check if my suspicion is right by changing your own setup quickly to delay for 2,5 seconds so we can be reasonably sure the initialization was fully done:

```typescript
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        var hasIdToken = this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken();
        var hasAccessToken = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();
        var hasAccess = (hasIdToken && hasAccessToken)
                   
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (!hasAccess) {
              console.log('AuthGuard: Token not valid');
              this.router.navigate(['landing']);
            } else {
              console.log('AuthGuard: Valid token');
            }
            resolve(hasAccess);
          }, 2500);
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where `hasValidAccessToken` incorrectly returned true for expired tokens. To address this issue, set `decreaseExpirationTimeBySec = 600000;` in your AuthConfig. This property, `clockSkewInSec`, represents the amount of time by which the client's clock is ahead of the server's clock. Adjusting it to zero ensures accurate token validation, particularly for token expiration.

```js
{
    // other configuration...
    decreaseExpirationTimeBySec = 600000;
}
```

If this helps, consider upvoting. Let me know if you need further assistance!